# SPRING BOOT deployable war file with maven and profiles in STS

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to make my spring boot app ready for easy packaging war using profiles (dev, prod ...) and maven 3 using spring source tool suite.

The profiles are set and working good, I can switch profiles in application.properties using param : spring.profiles.active

I've created application-{profiles}.properties and boot reads the property file accordingly with spring.profiles.active param set in application.properties

Now I create a maven run configuration, using in goals section : package spring-boot:repackage

and I also add in parameter section : spring.profiles.active with dev as value.

At the end I would like 3 run configurations with different values in spring.profiles.active so the package will be prepared for different environnements.

When I run the configuration with debug mode, I can see in the test section that my current param passed in maven is correctly used (if I set dev, I see in maven test that my dev DB is called, so reads the application-dev.properties file), but after when maven is generating the final war this param don't seem to be used anymore.

When I deploy the package, spring boot read spring.profiles.active if present in application.properties. If I remove this in application.properties, boot just use the params in application.properties

Am I doing something wrong ? I think it's during 'repackaging' that my param set in maven is lost.

I've also another question, I try to give a name on the final war with maven in plugin section but it doesn't seem to work like I was doing before with maven.

Here is the end of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>stdapps</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is a picture of my maven configuration :

[image: Maven run configuration]

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the spring boot maven plugin configuration, as described in the [plugin documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html), *warName* is not a valid parameter, *finalName* is.

Also, from my experience, even if the documentation says that the classifier param is optional, when I tried to configure the repackage goal with a final name and an output directory, when executing the command `mvn spring-boot:repackage` from a terminal, the result is a build failure and a error message indicating that classifier cannot be null. (bug?)

So this is the plugin configuration that works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>warName</finalName>
                <classifier>classifierName</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This generates warName-classifierName.war file in deployments folder in my  project.